# Notepad++: where I can get the NPPExec plugin for Windows?

Tags: windows, notepad++, plugins, compile, dll

When I Google "NppExec plugin", the first page is [this](https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec), but no dll found. Should I compile it starting from these files?

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "no DLL found"? There are bunch in releases here, in archives: https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/releases/tag/v087

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. I'd recommend deleting the question as this seems like a simple mislook.